# Is it possible to upgrade Jenkins from Jenkins it-self?

Tags: jenkins, upgrade

On *Manage Jenkins* I've a message that:

> New version of Jenkins (2.47) is available for download (changelog).

Is there any way of upgrading Jenkins from the GUI similar as it's done for the plugins?

I'm using Jenkins ver. 2.43 on Linux.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question so I will not post an answer but the ideal case should be having a Jenkins deployed with terraform and ansible (or puppet or chef ...) and upgrade the formulas for that.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking @kenorb... When there's a new Jenkins version it prompts you to ask if you want to install it. you mean besides that?

Comment: It's showing the message to upgrade and download WAR file, but I don't think the new version is available via Apt, so I'm looking for similar upgrade process as plugins.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In Windows, this is what I see when there is a new version available:
[image]

When you click the Upgrade Automatically button, Jenkins downloads and install the new war file itself.

Please, check [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade) for further details. There are some problems if you installed Jenkins from a Debian package.

> If you run Jenkins with `java -jar jenkins.war`, Jenkins will be able to update itself from the Manage Jenkins page. This is the simplest way to do automatic upgrades.

#### *nix/Mac

> If you've installed via the OS X installer, the `jenkins` running the process does not own the `.war` file. **To get auto-upgrade working, just fix the permissions so the `jenkins` user can write the WAR** (in `/Applications/Jenkins`).

#### Debian Package

> Using the Upgrade-Button from within Jenkins (available since 1.318) will not work if Jenkins was installed from a Debian package (results in permission denied errors when trying to download the new WAR file)!

#### Windows Auto-Upgrade

> If you install Jenkins as a Windows service, Jenkins will be able to update itself from the *Manage Jenkins* page.

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the existing jenkins.war file with the new one and then restart Jenkins.

This file is usually located in /usr/share/jenkins.

If this is not the case for your system, in Manage Jenkins -> System Information, it will display the path to the .war file under executable-war.

Comment: How does this answer the question ?